# How to insert data into influx db?

Tags: c#, influxdb

I have write this code to insert sample data into influx db but it failed to write and leads 400 bad request. i need to set the authentication to be none and insert this sample data into database.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("tablename,host=<ip>,region=us-west,category=details count=20 1614762030000000000");
        
    var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var url = "http://<ip>:<port>/write?db=Dbname";
    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url,data);

    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Any one please help on this!!

Am newbie to this :) :) Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you inspect the full response? Often there is a reason/description about the cause of the bad request.

Comment: Try use the C# library: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-csharp

Comment: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: @Magnetron i would like to do it through api